# rmarkdown comments or something similar

Tags: comments, warnings, r-markdown

[image]

When the rmarkdown file is knitted, there are something after the title area, as it is shown in the picture.

How to remove those?

I have set "warning=FALSE, comment=NA" in the r code chunk, but it does not work.

Some of the codes are as follows:

````
---
title: 'Validness Report by All Facilities'
subtitle: '2017-01-03 to 2017-01-09'
output: pdf_document
geometry: margin=0.5in
classoption: landscape
documentclass: article
---


```{r input, echo = FALSE, results = 'hide', cache = TRUE, 
warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, error=FALSE}

setwd("F:/")
dfDataIn_valid2 <- read.csv("full_valid.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```


```{r validness, echo = FALSE, results = 'hide', 
cache = TRUE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, error=FALSE}



# Check if required packages are installed. If not, install them.

packages <- c("rJava", "xlsxjars", "xlsx", "lubridate", "dplyr", "lazyeval")
lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE)

```
````

Comment: Please post the code that generated that.

Comment: yes, I attach the key part of them. I think the rest codes do not affect this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need chunk option `message` set to `FALSE`

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = 'hide', cache = TRUE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, error=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
````

Also, you don't need to repeat the options for each chunk; you could also just set them in the first one:

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, results = 'hide', cache = TRUE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, error=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```
````